# Getting the shape/outline of an HTML node in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

Is it possible to get the shape/outline of a DOM node in JavaScript? I would like to get some kind of representation of the shape or outline so that I can tell exactly which pixels the DOM node occupies. I can calculate the rectangle using width, height, and position, but this doesn't take into account the `border-radius` property, among others.

I know that I have access to all of the individual properties that will determine the rendered outline of a node (height, width, border-radius, etc), so I could, in JavaScript, reproduce the calculations the browser does. However, this would be pretty tedious and there would be a lot of edge cases.

Comment: Other stuff that could change the dimensions I think include `border-radius` and `transform`. Can't think of anything else and I think you could detect these properties too using JavaScript. Not familiar with any other method I think

Comment: @Ahmad Good call, thanks. Man, that makes it even more of a mess.

Comment: Don't forget transformations like rotates .. eww, that's a tough one. Imagine a square turned 45 degrees - same area, but now it is "wider" and "taller".

Comment: I +1 that question I wish there could be a descent way to get these info. I think the best is to write a jQuery plugin that would get all these information and store it in a variable.

Answer (score 0):

and don't forget that different browsers may render slightly different.
That is if you are interested in the padding and margin as well.